# Why does this RegEx have to be surrounded in parenthesis to match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I started with [this](https://github.com/yanni4night/node-ssi/blob/master/index.js#L27) RegExp:

```
 /<!--#\s*include\s+file=(['"])([^\r\n]+?)\1\s*-->/g
```

And I wanted it to match both of these lines:

```
<!--#include file="../header.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="../header.html"-->
```

In my first attempt, I changed `file` to `(file|virtual)` like so:

```
/<!--#\s*include\s+(file|virtual)=(['"])([^\r\n]+?)\1\s*-->/g
```

But, that didn't match anything. After a little playing around, I found that adding parenthesis around everything would get a match:

```
/(<!--#\s*include\s+(file|virtual)=(['"])([^\r\n]+?)\1\s*-->)/g
```

I don't understand why though - why didn't the first modification match, and why do the extra parenthesis fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it was the `\1` back refference near the end - it was supposed to match the opening `(['"])` with the same quote at the end. But when I added an extra capture group, then it was looking for a second `(file|virtual)` at the end of the file path.

The fix was to change it to `\2`.

This is the corrected RegExp:

```
/<!--#\s*include\s+(file|virtual)=(['"])([^\r\n]+?)\2\s*-->/g
```